# mod_rewrite add question mark if url shortener, else do something different

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a url shortener in my web app, like http://myProject1.example.com/76sBdFAf6L
This stuff should be redirected to http://myProject1.example.com/index.php?76sBdFAf6L -- adding a question mark, to convert the 76sBdFAf6L into a query string.

But, if a URL has NO link shortener code, it should just redirect to my root, eg http://myProject1.example.com/files/files.php should be redirected to http://www.example.com/projects/myProject1/files/files.php

What are the mod_rewrite conditions for such rules? 
Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these to the htaccess file in your document root, or in your vhost/server config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9A-Za-z]+)$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```